# easy loop through json api array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This jquery code is displaying json data inside span html input elements. But i failed to implement for loop to display array objects of movie genres.

Right now it's just 0 index of array but i wanna display all..

```
$("#txt-movie-genres").val(json.genres[0].name)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'movie/',
    movie_id,
    key = '?api_key=e9dfeccf734a61b9a52d9d7660f0d0a1';

  $('button').click(function() {
    var input = $('#movie').val(),
      movie_id = encodeURI(input);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url + mode + movie_id + key,
      async: false,
      jsonpCallback: 'testing',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'jsonp',

      success: function(json) {

        // grab the span elements by ID and replace their text with the json text

        //   $("#movie-title").text(json.title);
        $("#txt-movie-title").val(json.title)

        $("#txt-movie-genres").val(json.genres[0].name)
        console.dir(json);
      },

      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="movie" type="text" /><button>Search</button>

<h1>Movie info:</h1>
<p>Movie title: <span id="span-movie-title"></span> </p>

<div class="input-group">
  <input id="txt-movie-title" name="title" type="text" />
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    Movie Name
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input id="txt-movie-genres" name="genres" type="text" />
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    Movie Genre
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new input for each element of the array or display comma separated names in single input?

Comment: yes! so that can be " Action, Adventure, Horror " etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("#txt-movie-genres").val(json.genres.map(g => g.name).join(",");
```

Which will create an array of names and then join them into a comma delimited string.

Comment: exactly what i was about to write, +1 for this answer

Comment: It does. map and that cool syntax are both ES6.
var arr = [];
for(key in json.genres) {
   arr.push(json.genres[key].name);
}
$("#txt-movie-genres").val(arr.join(","));

Answer (score 0):

You could covert `json.genres` arrays to array of genres names using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) methidand then join them to comma separated string using [join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp):

```
var names = $.map(json.genres, function() { return this.name }).join(",");
```